# Prevent Cloudfront from forwarding part of path to origin server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

**Background:**
I have an S3 Bucket ( Origin 1) that serves a static website under a the domain `example.com` using Cloudfront.

**Goal:**

Additionaly i want `example.com/subfolder` to serve content from `second.com` ( Origin 2). for the following to be true `example.com/subfolder = second.com`

**Currently:**

Under the Cloudfront distribution i set up Origin 1 with behavior `Default (*)`
and Origin 2 with behavior `/subfolder*`

**Problem:**

When going to `example.com/subfolder` i am being served `second.com/subfolder`

**Q:**
How and where would I adjust Cloudfronts behavior to not forward the first part of the url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CloudFront doesn't natively support this.

The original request path is forwarded intact to the origin server, with only one exception: if the origin has an [Origin Path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath) configured, that value is added to the beginning of the path before the request is sent to the origin (and, of course, this  doesn't help, here).

However, you can modify the path during CloudFront processing using a [Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) Origin Request trigger.

This type of trigger fires only on cache misses -- after the CloudFront cache is checked but before the request is sent to the origin -- and allows modification of the request that will be sent to the origin... including the path.  The response from the origin, if cacheable, is stored in CloudFront under the path originally requested by the browser (not the modified path), so caching still works correctly even when the trigger modifies the path.

The trigger code to remove the first level from the path might look something like this:

```js
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;           // extract the request object
    request.uri = request.uri.replace(/^\/[^\/]+\//,'/');  // modify the URI
    return callback(null, request);                        // return control to CloudFront
};
```

There's more discussion of this in [my answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31574851/1695906) at Stack Overflow, which is the original source of the code snippet above.  It was originally written in Node.js 6.10 but is still compatible with the Lambda@Edge interface, which now uses newer versions of Node.  Alternately, if you prefer, the trigger code can also be written in Python.

You might also need to arrange for `/subfolder` to be redirected to `/subfolder/` so that paths relative to the root of the second origin are correctly canonicalized.

Answer (score 2):

CloundFront *does* natively support this!

There is another solution, which doesn't require Lambda@Edge.

Let's call your existing CloudFront distribution **CF-D1**.

1. Create a new CloudFront distribution, **CF-D2**, with origin domain `second.com`
2. Set the origin path of **CF-D2** to `path` such that `second.com/path/subfolder` returns a `403` or `404` error. In my case this was just `/`.
3. Create a custom error response in **CF-D2** that returns a `200` and the path on `second.com` that you actually want to serve. Again, this may be just `/`
4. Create a new origin on **CF-D1** with the domain of **CF-D2** (eg. `v786bh23iuy8v4.cloudfront.net`)
5. Create a new behavior in **CF-D1** that directs the path pattern `/subfolder` to the  new **CF-D2** origin.

Now when you try to access `example.com/subfolder` on **CF-D1**, CloudFront will direct the request to `second.com/path/subfolder` on **CF-D2** which gives a `403` or `404`. So then it will serve the custom error response of **CF-D2** which is `second.com/` (or whatever you set as the error response).

Comment: that may work, but... just thinking about it feels like some kind of violation 